# How can I filter features using the geometry parameter in pygeoapi?

Tags: geometry, latitude-longitude

How to filter for a feature using geometry parameter in pygeoapi?

I tried using the same way as mentioned in the documentation but it didn't work. It didn't give the filtered results.

I want to filter the data by giving the longitude and latitude of the record.